# Speech to Text Conversion - NOt getting desired output

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to do speech to text conversion for one of my project. But I am not getting the desired result. Can you pls let me know what should I modify for the code to work?

```
package com.example.speechtotext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private TextView txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                txtText.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            txtText.setText(text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
}
```

There are no compilation or runtime errors. As soon as I click the "Speak Now" button on the emulator, it says that Oops!! Your device doesn't support speech to text. I tried to install the .apk in my android and check it.It throws a pop up msg that "Connection Problem" with a warning mark and two buttons on the bottom for "Speak again " and "cancel".
Pls tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private ListView mList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);
         Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
         mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your device needs to have the Intent which will be able to recognise voice. If such an Intent doesn't exist, you get the error you mentioned.

Try installing "Google Voice Search" app from the [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC52b2ljZXNlYXJjaCJd).

Comment: When I turned Internet ON, I was able to Speech to Text conversion with my actual code. But the time it takes to do conversion is little high and at the same time, it is not converting in a very efficient manner. I will try out with the code you had mentioned.